# Numpy 2D array: change all values to the right of NaNs

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

### Situation

I have a 2D Numpy array that contains some `nan` values. Simplified example:

```
arr = np.array([[3, 5, np.nan, 2, 4],
                [9, 1, 3, 5, 1],
                [8, np.nan, 3, np.nan, 7]])
```

which looks like this in console output:

```
array([[  3.,   5.,  nan,   2.,   4.],
       [  9.,   1.,   3.,   5.,   1.],
       [  8.,  nan,   3.,  nan,   7.]])
```

### Problem

I am looking for a good way to set all values to the right of existing `nan` values to `nan` as well. In other words, I need to convert the example array to this:

```
array([[  3.,   5.,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  9.,   1.,   3.,   5.,   1.],
       [  8.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

I know how to accomplish this with loops, but I would imagine that a method that uses only Numpy vectorized operations would be much more efficient. Is there anyone who could help me find such a method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach with [`cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) and [`boolean-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) -

```
arr[np.isnan(arr).cumsum(1)>0] = np.nan
```

For performance, it might be better to use [`np.maximum.accumulate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) -

```
arr[np.maximum.accumulate(np.isnan(arr),axis=1)] = np.nan
```

One more way with a bit twisted use of [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
n = arr.shape[1]
mask = np.isnan(arr)
idx = mask.argmax(1)
idx[~mask.any(1)] = n
arr[idx[:,None] <= np.arange(n)] = np.nan
```

Sample run -

```
In [96]: arr
Out[96]: 
array([[  3.,   5.,  nan,   2.,   4.],
       [  9.,   1.,   3.,   5.,   1.],
       [  8.,  nan,   3.,  nan,   7.]])

In [97]: arr[np.maximum.accumulate(np.isnan(arr),axis=1)] = np.nan

In [98]: arr
Out[98]: 
array([[  3.,   5.,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  9.,   1.,   3.,   5.,   1.],
       [  8.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

**Benchmarking**

Approaches -

```
def func1(arr):
    arr[np.isnan(arr).cumsum(1)>0] = np.nan

def func2(arr):
    arr[np.maximum.accumulate(np.isnan(arr),axis=1)] = np.nan

def func3(arr): # @ MSeifert's suggestion
    mask = np.isnan(arr); 
    accmask = np.cumsum(mask, out=mask, axis=1); 
    arr[accmask] = np.nan

def func4(arr):
    mask = np.isnan(arr); 
    np.maximum.accumulate(mask,axis=1, out = mask)
    arr[mask] = np.nan

def func5(arr):
    n = arr.shape[1]
    mask = np.isnan(arr)
    idx = mask.argmax(1)
    idx[~mask.any(1)] = n
    arr[idx[:,None] <= np.arange(n)] = np.nan
```

Timings -

```
In [201]: # Setup inputs
     ...: arr = np.random.rand(5000,5000)
     ...: arr.ravel()[np.random.choice(range(arr.size), 10000, replace=0)] = np.nan
     ...: arr1 = arr.copy()
     ...: arr2 = arr.copy()
     ...: arr3 = arr.copy()
     ...: arr4 = arr.copy()
     ...: arr5 = arr.copy()
     ...: 

In [202]: %timeit func1(arr1)
     ...: %timeit func2(arr2)
     ...: %timeit func3(arr3)
     ...: %timeit func4(arr4)
     ...: %timeit func5(arr5)
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 149 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 90.5 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 88.8 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 88.5 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 75.3 ms per loop
```

Broadcasting based one seems to be doing quite well!

Comment: If performance is a concern the `mask = np.isnan(arr); accmask = np.cumsum(mask, out=mask, axis=1); arr[accmask] = np.nan` will be even faster (and probably more memory efficient) :-)

Comment: @MSeifert Pretty comparable to the accummulate one, good suggestion! Consider adding that to your post! Though too much of code in it ;)

Comment: @MSeifert Added timings for that alongwith others.

Comment: on my computer your `func5` is slower than `func2`, `func3` and `func4`. But given that it's a close run I added a numba solution that beats all of them by a factor 1.5 :)

Comment: @MSeifert Sure, a JIT based one would be nice here.

Answer (score 4):

Use boolean indexing and some sort of accumulator (I used `np.cumsum` here):

```
>>> mask = np.cumsum(np.isnan(arr), axis=1).astype(bool)

>>> arr[mask] = np.nan

>>> arr
array([[  3.,   5.,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  9.,   1.,   3.,   5.,   1.],
       [  8.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

---

As already pointed out in the comments using the `out`-parameter might speed things up and avoid creating another temporary array:

```
def put_nans_right_of_nans(arr):
    mask = np.isnan(arr)
    mask = np.cumsum(mask, out=mask, axis=1)
    arr[mask] = np.nan
```

---

Given that I'm quite a [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) fanatic I want to show a solution that is straightforward to implement and beats all other approaches in terms of performance and memory useage:

```
import numba as nb
import math

@nb.njit
def nan_items_rightofnans(arr):
    x, y = arr.shape[0], arr.shape[1]

    for row_no in range(x):
        nanfound = False
        for col_no in range(y):
            if nanfound:
                arr[row_no, col_no] = np.nan
            elif math.isnan(arr[row_no, col_no]):
                nanfound = True

    return arr
```